# Why do residuals cluster in two group?

Tags: logistic, residuals, outliers

I am running a logistic regression in a sample with ~150,000 observations. I am predicting three different outcomes, x, y, and z, that occur in ~10,000, ~4,000, and ~2,000 cases respectively (for each I am running a separate glm).

When checking the residuals, they cluster in two groups, with most of the residuals from non-cases in one group, and most of the residuals from cases in the other group. Depending on the outcome, the proportion of cases that represent outlier residuals (if outlier is defined as lying >2 standard deviations from the mean), is between 0.95 and 0.99. So the model seems to be having issue with predicting cases accurately.

Below is generic code that leads to this result. The figure is for the outcome with ~10,000 cases. The left part of the distribution (around 0) are residuals for non-cases. On the right (around 2) are residuals for cases.

```
model <- glm(formula, data = df, family = 'binomial')
residuals <- residuals(model, type = "deviance")
df_with_residuals <- data.frame(df, residuals = residuals)
hist(df_with_residuals$residuals, 100)
```

[image]

What is likely to be causing this issue and how can it be rectified? Thanks.

Comment: In general, I don't think residuals are a very useful way of thinking about a binary classification problem. You would always expect them to some extent to cluster into two distributions, one for each class. This is because all probabilities are bounded between 0 and 1. Imagine your probabilities are mostly between 0.2-0.8. Now you subtract the target value, you have one distribution between 0.2 and 0.8 and another between -0.8 and -0.2, barely overlapping. I don't understand your chart though, I don't see how you can have residuals with values greater than 2.

Comment: @gazza89 these are deviance residuals not the probabilities; as such, they can fall outside of [0,1]. The larger they are, the poorer the fit.